# grep tail and head wrong result

Tags: linux, grep, tail, head

I want to show the 3 first lines and the 2 last lines that contain a word. 
I tried a grep command but it's not showing what I want.

`grep -w it /usr/include/stdio.h | head -3 | tail -2`

It only display the 2nd and 3nd lines that contain "it" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `tail` never receives the output of `grep`, but rather only the first 3 lines of the file. To make this work reliably you either need to `grep` twice, once with `head` and once with `tail` or multiplex the stream, e.g.:

```
grep -w it /usr/include/stdio.h |
tee >(head -n3 > head-of-file) >(tail -n2 > tail-of-file) > /dev/null
cat head-of-file tail-of-file
```

Output here:

```
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   or due to the implementation it is a cancellation point and
/* Try to acquire ownership of STREAM but do not block if it is not
```

Comment: It works, but i'm asked to do it in only one command. How could i grep twice for the head and the tail ?

Comment: @avanabana: You can't with `head` and `tail`, `sed` on the other hand can do it

Comment: @Thor that's not true, see MahmoudKsemtini answer

Comment: @FernandoSantagata: interesting. However, the solution only works with redirection from a file, and not in a pipe-line, so I think my point still stands

Answer (score 2):

You can simply append the results of head and tail :

```
{ head -3 ; tail -2 ;} < /usr/include/stdio.h
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
grep -A 2 -B 3 "it" /usr/include/stdio.h
```

-A = After context of 2 lines to the matching word "it"

-B = After context of 3 lines to the matching word "it"

you can also add -W if you really need a regex.

expected output:

line 1

line 2

line that contains it

line 4

line 5

line 6

Comment: It prints all the file

Comment: does the word it is repeated throughout the file? if so, then the entire file may be the output. say if the second line matches, so line1 to line 5 would be printed, and the next match is on line 5, then line 6 to line 8 would be printed and so on

Comment: may be can you post a snip of the file?

Comment: it's the stdio.h file located on /usr/include

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /usr/include/stdio.h | grep -w it | head -3 | tail -2
```